# Jira Find Users API call querying an email address that includes a plus sign

Tags: email, jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to use the Jira Rest API v3 call to [Find users](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-user-search/#api-rest-api-3-user-search-get) to search for users by email address. The `GET` call works fine like with this syntax: `/rest/api/3/user/search?query={EmailAddress}`.

However, in the case where the email address includes a `+` (plus) sign in the username portion of the email address, instead of searching on that email address, it performs a global search on `displayName` and `emailAddress` using the chars from both sides of the `+` sign.

For example, searching for `john@example.com` returns just the user record with that email address. However, a search for `john+test@example.com` will return any user with an `emailAddress` or `displayName` that contains `john` **OR** contains `test` (and interestingly, does not limit the second one to be items containing `test@example.com`). It seems like adding the `+` is translated by the Jira API into an `OR` search for two different fragments of text.

How can I search for users on the Jira Rest API having an email address that contains a `+` (plus) sign (a common, legal character) in the username of the email?

Answer (score 1):

A `+` (plus) sign in the querystring of a url has a special value: it is translated into a space. In order to get the desired functionality, you need to UrlEncode the email address, which will change `john+test@example.com` into `john%2Btest%40gmail.com`. The API will then search on this string.

Keeping the unencoded `+` sign resulted in two terms separated by a space being processed by the API, which treated these as `OR`'d search terms.